# Windows Explorer does not show an "Eject" context menu entry for a virtual device marked removeable

Tags: windows, winapi, kernel

I have a virtual block device driver up and running. It works pretty much ok, however, so far I couldn't get the eject menu item in the drive's context menu of the Windows Explorer to appear.

The device is created with IOCreateDevice device type FILE_DEVICE_DISK with FILE_REMOVABLE_MEDIA characteristics. A dosdevice symlink mounts the device as drive letter.
The device handles IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECT_MEDIA and IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_HOTPLUG_INFO.

I am not sure what is missing. Is there any documentation about this ? Google and MSDN do not have much information about this.

Answer (score 0):

I most likely figured it out:
I need to convert it to a plug and play driver.